# Update Snap from another Snap

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

I wanted to know if it's possible to update a Snap from another Snap, and if its possible to host your snaps privately for this purpose instead of hosting it on the canonical public repository.

The functionality would be something like:

1- Snap A downloads from an endpoint a new snap version of Snap B

2- Snap A upgrades Snap B with the downloaded version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Potentially this might work, using the `snapd-control` interface. There was a lengthy [thread](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/dynamically-manage-plugs-and-slots-of-an-interface/169) about this recently on the snapcraft forum on a similar topic.

While it may be technically possible, the user loses out here as the `Snap B` in your example won't have been validated by the usual store checks. It also won't auto-update as the system will see the snap has having been 'side-loaded'.

The `Snap B` could also contain anything, potentially malicious. As a result, the security team may not allow the use of snapd-control in this instance for `Snap A`.